# string is getting filled using keypad,but passed empty

Tags: c, pic

```
int amjad=0;
char PASS[25];
char PASSEDT[25];

void main()
{
    char Password[25];

    Lcd_init();
    Keypad_init();
    Lcd_Clear();
    int i2=0;

    //here
    while (PORTCbits.RC3==1 &&amjad==0 )
    {
        Lcd_Clear();
        Lcd_Set_Cursor(1,1);
        Lcd_Write_String("Program Mode");
        Lcd_Set_Cursor(2,1);
        Lcd_Write_String(PASSEDT);
        key=GetKey();
        if (key=='*')
        {
            Lcd_Clear();
            Lcd_Set_Cursor(1,1);
            Lcd_Write_String("Password Saved");
            Lcd_Set_Cursor(2,1);
            Lcd_Write_String(PASSEDT);
            memset(Password,0,sizeof(Password));
            while(1)
            {
                if(PORTCbits.RC3==1)
                {
                    amjad=0;
                }
                else if(PORTCbits.RC3==0)
                {
                    __delay_ms(100);
                    Lcd_Clear();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            PASSEDT[i2]=key;
            i2++;
            Lcd_Set_Cursor(2,1);
        }
        //Lcd_Write_String(PASSEDT);
    }


}
//here

loop:
    while(PORTCbits.RC4==1)
    {//
        Lcd_Set_Cursor(1,1);
        Lcd_Write_String("Enter");
        Lcd_Write_String(PASSEDT);
        PORTCbits.RC1=0;
```

Hello I am filling the `PASSEDT` using keypad and it's getting printed on the LCD fine.

However when `PORTCbits.RC3=0` and I am displaying it in`loop` only `Enter` is showing, any help is appreciated.

(the LCD functions does exactly what it's name is)

Comment: When `PORTCbits.RC3 = 0`, then there is `Lcd_Clear();` when `PORTCbits.RC3==0`, and then `break;`, then the other  `while (PORTCbits.RC3==1 &&amjad==0 )` exits, then you go after the loop to `Lcd_Write_String("Enter");` so only `Enter` will show up.

Comment: @KamilCuk Lcd_Clear(); only clears the "display screen" not the variables,however when i am using PASSEDT later on it's empty.

Comment: Och, so confusing description. So what you really mean, is that the `Lcd_Write_String(PASSEDT);` line in `while(PORTCbits.RC4==1)` prints nothing? Why did you post so much code? What if you put `Lcd_Set_Cursor(2,1);` before this line? Do you have uart output? Debugger? Any leds? Can you `printf`? The `PASSEDT` inside `while (PORTCbits.RC3==1 &&amjad==0 )` get's printed out correctly?

Comment: @KamilCuk printf is basically Lcd_Write_String("...") but on LCD,i had to post so much code to explain from the start otherwise i might get reported.(this barely the top of the iceberg of the code)